# how to set user's gmail account to auto forward new mail to another email address

Tags: php, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to find a way to forward new gmail mails from user's inbox to other email address. this email address also belongs to user but with different domain. its like getting a copy of new mail from gmail account.

so basically i got the oAuth2 working. i looked around the new gmail api for code that will edit user gmail account to forward to another email address and no luck here. it seems that gmail api (PHP) is in beta stage and email forwarding not supported yet.

any lead would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: done with authenticating users using google api client library(PHP). im using google/apiclient:1.* for libs with https://mail.google.com/ scope. now what i want is after the user authenticate, i want to enable user account to auto forward new mails to another email address. any help ?

Comment: Google search engine is your friend https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#java  No idea how to use it its an old gdata lib so should be a pain to get working.  Again all I did was google "Gmail api forward"

Comment: going to try this. thanks man!

Comment: no luck. no php library that could do this.

Comment: @JohnSmith did you find anything for this? I also want to achieve something similar